# Oracle current_timestamp provides different values in same session

Tags: oracle, timestamp, default-value

We have a table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE tokens (
  token VARCHAR2(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
  insertedOn TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

If we connect to the DB with SQL Developer we have the following:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL
-- 25-AGO-23 17:15:01,515019000 EUROPE/BERLIN

SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;
-- EUROPE/BERLIN
```

But if we insert a row from SQL Developer during the same session:

```
INSERT INTO tokens (token, username) VALUES ('123', 'john');
```

the row is inserted with an unexpected timestamp (-1 hour):

```
SELECT * FROM tokens;
-- 123 john 16:15:27,929125000
```

Why is the timestamp inserted with a different value?

---

The database is Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition 10.2.0.4.0

The session parameters are the following:

[image]

Comment: Your client app (SQL Developer in this case) may have a different time zone/offset setting. The JDBC driver may be doing the time zone "adapting" behind the scenes automatically.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table, which overrides the default - maybe to `systimestamp`?

Comment: There is no trigger on the table

Answer (score 1):

`insertedOn TIMESTAMP` is defined as a `TIMESTAMP` which does not include timezone. The function `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` however, returns a different datatype, one that *does* include the timezone (`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`). In order to insert this datatype into a `TIMESTAMP` column, Oracle has to convert based on your timezone settings, and that's where the shift is happening.

To fix, redefine your column:

```
CREATE TABLE tokens (
  token VARCHAR2(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
  insertedOn TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

The same by the way is true of PL/SQL variables. Any time you store the result of a `SYSTIMESTAMP` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in either a variable or a table column, ensure the type is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or it'll convert and likely shift based on your timezone settings and that can lead to some unwanted results.

Comment: Or use `LOCALTIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. `LOCALTIMESTAMP` returns the local time as `TIMESTAMP` value without time zone information .

Comment: Oracle will use your session time zone when implicitly converting from `timestamp` to `timestamp with time zone`, but the other way is a simpler cast that just discards the time zone info? [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MHbbdSM1)

Comment: These are all valid suggestions on how to _avoid_ the problem, but I still don't know what's causing this very unexpected behavior. I understand that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP includes the TZ and TIMESTAMP does not: but given that the current session has a well known timezone, I do not understand why the SELECT returns X and the insert gives me X-1